# Yellow anti-rotation washer, Shimano Nexus 3 speed with trailer?

Tags: brakes, safety, trailer, nexus

Should I keep or remove the yellow anti-rotation washer when installing a child trailer to my e-bike (EcoRide with Shimano Nexus 3 speed)? The trailer installs through the wheel axle (see attached img.)

[image: Shimano nexus with trailer mounted through wheel axle]

Comment: Do you have to make a choice, can you keep it and install the trailer too? Do you have a black one that’s like the yellow one but on the other side? A follow on question would be which side does the yellow/black go on (I think it’s the opposite side but don’t have the answer for how essential that is)

Comment: Check with your bike dealer whether Shimano requires the yellow washer to be used.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the yellow washer is a anti-rotation washer - one that fits in a slotted dropout and prevents the internally geared hub from rotating with the axle - then yes it needs to be in place.

Comment: Thanks! I'll put the trailer attachment outside the yellow washer.

Answer (score 4):

Bit late but posting this for any future people asking this question. My LBS helped me with this. The inner nut on on the axle (between the dropout and the hub) you can remove that and replace it with a thinner nut.
Then place the yellow washer reversed on the inside of the dropout and you can put the trailer hitch on the outside.

Have been using this for the past 2 years